# Как вызвать функциональный компонент из компонента с состоянием в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь прорешивать книгу React and Redux стр 135
Есть функциональный компонент, рисующий звездочку:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "material-ui-next";

const styles = {
  star: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    margin: 2,
    float: "left",
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    clipPath: `polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);`
  }
};

const Star = ({ selected = true, classes }) => {
  return <div className={classes.star} />;
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Star);
```

Импортирую его, и пытаюсь отрисовать в методе render в StarRating:

```
import React from "react";
import { Star } from "./Star";
import { Component } from "react";

class StarRating extends Component {
  displayName: "star-rating";

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      totalStar: 5
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { totalStar } = this.state;
    console.log(`totalStar: ${totalStar}`);
    return <div>{[...Array(totalStar)].map((n, index) => <Star />)} </div>;
  }
}

export default StarRating;
```

но получаю непонятную ошибку для меня 
Invariant Violation
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `StarRating`.
▶ 26 stack frames were collapsed.
evaluate
/src/index.js:17:7

Код тут:https://codesandbox.io/s/xj5lkxxp2p

Comment: У вас переменная Star не эспортируемая, но судя по тому что она завернута в декоратор - можно просто убрать "{ }" в импорте

Comment: @DiDex по идее, я у меня есть строка export default withStyles(styles)(Star); в конце Star, это и есть экспортируемость или подразумевается что-то другое?

Comment: Есть такая строка, и когда вы будете вызывать imort Stars from './Stars', она будет работать, но когда вы вызываете переменную {Stars}, он ищет в файле export const Stars, а его нет, и пишет "You likely forgot to export your component from the file"

Comment: получилось ли у Вас решить проблему? я так же пытаюсь из класса вызвать функцию и использовать useState и вызывается ошибка. поиском нашел этот вопрос.